# is there a syntax in javascript new features where i can extract object values into new object with same key and values?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```
let obj = { a: 1, b:2, c:3}
```

I can do

```
let {a,b,c}  = obj
```

but i want an object with just 'a' and 'b' as key and same value as in obj

do i have a syntax for that one

it is basically filtering out the keys but do we have some succint syntax for this one because I constantly do

```
let test = {
  a: obj.a,
  b: obj.b
}
```

Answer (score 1):

how about `let n = ({a,b} = obj) && {a,b}`?

Comment: How about not using global variables?

Comment: @Bergi so the typical answer to this basically doing the same thin but because that is happening inside a function those variables dies inside function scope, (the parameters of the functions), but the OP just wanted to avoid calling another function to filter it

Comment: You can do it without a function as well - there are many ways - but you have to declare `a` and `b` to *some* scope. IIFEs are just quite concise.

Answer (score 0):

Using object destructuring, Hope this helps

```js
var obj = {"a":1, "b":2, "c":3}
var test = (({a, b}) => ({a, b}))(obj);

console.log(test);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer .i know it can be done... i wanted to know if there is a syntax .

Comment: If you are looking for exact syntax, I don't think so It's available, but would definitely love to know if a syntax exists in js. Otherwise, you will need to use better techniques (or one-liner) or your own function to do that which should be better than `let test = {
  a: obj.a,
  b: obj.b
}`

Answer (score 0):

The following does this:

```
let result = {}
Object.keys(obj)
    .filter(e=>![LIST WITH KEYS TO FILTER].includes(e))
    .forEach(e=> result[e]= obj[e])
```

It gets all keys from `obj`, filters out some keys and pushes the values of the leftover keys to the result object.

Comment: thanks for the answer .i know it can be done... i wanted to know if there is a syntax .